# Rails5 + JQuery progress bar not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

Implementing a JQuery progress bar so when you scroll down 
it should show a green bar across the top. When I start scrolling the progress bar does not appear. I inspect element on the bar  the element it shows the width % going up see screenshot

[image]

[image]

scroll.js

```
$(document).on('scroll', function() {

  var pixelsFromTop = $(document).scrollTop()

  var documentHeight = $(document).height()
  var windowHeight = $(window).height()

  var difference = documentHeight - windowHeight

  var percentage = 100 * pixelsFromTop / difference

  $('.bar').css('width', percentage + '%')

})
```

show.html.erb

```
<div class="progress">
   <div class="bar"></div>
</div>

<section class="day">

    <h2><%= "To make #{number_to_currency @product.revenue}" %></h2>
    <p class="lead"><%= "You need to make #{number_to_currency @product.monthly_amount} a month" %><br/>
    <%= "You need to make #{number_to_currency @product.daily_amount} a day" %></p>
</section>


<section class="people"> 

    <h2>Or if you create and sell a product</h2>
        <table>
        <p class="lead"><%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 10,000 people to buy a
        #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_10000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 5,000 people to buy a
        #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_5000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 2,000 people to buy a
        #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_2000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 1,000 people to buy a
     #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_1000} product" %><br/>

        <%= "To make #{@product.revenue } 100 people to buy a
     #{number_to_currency @product.create_and_sell_product_100} product" %></p>
        </table>
</section>
```

looking at the logs its not finding scroll but its showing the width element going up, (see prev screenshot)

```
Started GET "/products/scroll.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-14 12:27:17 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"scroll"}
  Product Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=scroll):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:67:in `set_product'
```

**products controller.rb**

```
  def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end
```

I have this in my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :products

  root 'products#new'
end


Started POST "/products" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 17:03:11 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZU4tSNn0PsbSL2CTB45yIuBlrn5OePTYPSbIcdKThzJuu/k7GsiIhFf7JJ98pC5NmhGVg5QyekokpzR1s4tv4A==", "product"=>{"revenue"=>"2000", "months"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Show Me How Much to Charge!"}
   (0.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (3.5ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("revenue", "months", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["revenue", "2000.0"], ["months", 2], ["created_at", "2017-08-16 16:03:11.679460"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-16 16:03:11.679460"]]
   (46.6ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/products/82
Completed 302 Found in 57ms (ActiveRecord: 51.0ms)


Started GET "/products/82" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 17:03:11 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"82"}
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 82], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering products/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 398ms (Views: 395.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/products/scroll.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-16 17:03:12 +0100
Processing by ProductsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"scroll"}
  Product Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 0], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=scroll):

app/controllers/products_controller.rb:67:in `set_product'
```

[image]

Comment: What triggers this request `Started GET "/products/scroll.js"`? It conflicts with **resourceful show route** and since Rails expects `:id` in the url, so it is treating `scroll` as `id` which resulted in that error.

Comment: In my routes I have resources :products https://github.com/neilp666/product_pricing_calculator

Comment: That is ok, but I want to know what triggered this request `Started GET "/products/scroll.js"` ?

Comment: I go to the root 'products#new'  add info to the products/_form.html.erb, . Hit submit. It goes to the show page -http://localhost:3000/products/82. Added the heroku logs which shows the triggered request

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Product with 'id'=scroll)

is triggered by **incorrect asset path**. When you look into `app/layouts/application.html.erb`, you will see this

```
<script src="scroll.js"></script>
```

The **url for src is wrong**. This then served as `/products/scroll.js` which conflicts with `/products/:id` and resulted in that error. You have `scroll.js` in `/app/assets/javascripts` folder, so you need to use `/assets/scroll.js`. Changing it to like below should fix the error

```
<script src="/assets/scroll.js"></script>
```

**OR**

Just call it from the `application.js` by including it like this

```
//= require scroll
```

which generates

```
<script src="/assets/scroll.js?body=1"></script>
```

I suggest you read about [*Asset Pipeline*](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to understand better.

Comment: Added the code & it works but only if add some text in the progress div class.  if I don't add any text it does not show the progress bar.  But thanks  & I will check out the asset pipeline again!